# Implement Camera behaviour as in Google's Messenger application

Tags: android, camera, facebook-messenger

So I am looking for some tips on how to implement Camera behaviour similar to Google's Messenger or Facebook Messenger app? So that camera preview is displayed where keyboard is, and on swipe up it goes into full screen camera preview. Any suggestions?